# SQL update query nested / join select

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I have these 2 tables:

**table1**

```
number (int) | time_stamp (datetime2) | number2 (int) | time_stamp2 (datetime2)
--------------------------------------------------------
20           | '2017-08-01 01:00:00'  | null          | null
100          | '2017-08-01 01:00:00'  | null          | null
```

**table2**

```
number (int)  | time_stamp (datetime2)
--------------------------
50            | '2017-08-01 01:01:01'
70            | '2017-08-01 01:01:02'
80            | '2017-08-01 01:01:03'
102           | '2017-08-01 01:01:04'
100           | '2017-08-01 01:01:05'
140           | '2017-08-01 01:01:06'
200           | '2017-08-01 01:01:07'
50            | '2017-08-01 01:01:08'
300           | '2017-08-01 01:01:09'
400           | '2017-08-01 01:01:10'
```

I want to update table 1 in that scenario:

```
update table1 set number2 = table2.number2, time_stamp2 = table2.timestamp
    where table1.number - table2.number <= -50 and table2.number - table2.(previousNumberByTimeStamp) >= 30
```

by the first occurrence of `table2.time_stamp` and `table1.time_stamp < table2.time_stamp`.

I'm having problem with the `previousNumberByTimeStamp`.
How can I get that information from the table?

This is the result I want to achieve for that example:

**table1**

```
number (int) | time_stamp (datetime2) | number2 (int) | time_stamp2 (datetime2)
--------------------------------------------------------
20           | '2017-08-01 01:00:00'  | 140           | '2017-08-01 01:01:06'
100          | '2017-08-01 01:00:00'  | 200           | '2017-08-01 01:01:07'
```

Comment: Can you try to explain your business rules here? I have read this several times and each time I read it makes less and less sense to me.

Comment: Yes I'll try to explain better: You need to find a number in the second table such as his previous number by the time stamp have a difference of X number. And the same number have difference of Y number from the number in table1. then you need to set that number into number2 of table1 and his time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this version:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE 
(number int, time_stamp datetime2, number2 int, time_stamp2 datetime2);

INSERT @table1 (number,time_stamp)
VALUES (20, '2017-08-01 01:00:00'),
        (100, '2017-08-01 01:00:00');

DECLARE @table2 TABLE 
(number int, time_stamp datetime2);

INSERT @table2 (number,time_stamp)
VALUES (50 ,'2017-08-01 01:01:01'),
        (70 ,'2017-08-01 01:01:02'),
        (80 ,'2017-08-01 01:01:03'),
        (102,'2017-08-01 01:01:04'),
        (100,'2017-08-01 01:01:05'),
        (140,'2017-08-01 01:01:06'),
        (200,'2017-08-01 01:01:07'),
        (50 ,'2017-08-01 01:01:08'),
        (300,'2017-08-01 01:01:09'),
        (400,'2017-08-01 01:01:10');

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT number, time_stamp, lag(number) over(ORDER BY time_stamp) prev
        FROM @table2
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.number2 = x.number,
    t1.time_stamp2 = x.time_stamp
    FROM @table1 t1
    OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT top(1) cte.number, cte.time_stamp 
                        FROM cte 
                        WHERE t1.time_stamp < cte.time_stamp 
                            AND t1.number - cte.number <= -50 
                            and cte.number - cte.prev >= 30 
                        ORDER BY cte.time_stamp
                ) AS x;

SELECT * FROM @table1;
```

Output:

```
number      time_stamp                  number2     time_stamp2
----------- --------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------
20          2017-08-01 01:00:00.0000000 140         2017-08-01 01:01:06.0000000
100         2017-08-01 01:00:00.0000000 200         2017-08-01 01:01:07.0000000
```

Comment: Seems amazing, I'm gonna test it on my big data... hope it works fast. once I see it works as I wanted will mark it as answered.

Comment: @MoranBarzilay, have you tested performance of this script on big data?

Comment: Yes, its bad. Lets say that table1 having 100 rows and table2 with 10 million rows then this query take huge amount of time. Don't know how much time yet, still running it.

Comment: Do you have index on table2.time_stamp ASC?

Comment: In this case, I think, you should optimize this part of query `AND t1.number - cte.number <= -50 and cte.number - cte.prev >= 30` to force seek by `time_stamp` and `number` instead of scan on table2

Comment: Yes, I do have index on it. For now its running for 1 hour and 30 minutes and from the looks of it only 2 rows out of 150 are finished.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: Just for the record, I just checked it on 1 row only for table1. 22~23 minutes run time. table2 with around 15 million rows.

Comment: If you have index on `table2.number`, predicate `number > table1.number` will use it, but predicate `number + 1 > table1.number` will not.  [Indexed Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns) can help you.